# Find a file with a matching pattern in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, unix

I am trying to find a file in Linux box. It ends with a timestamp pattern, 
e.g:

- `MY_TEST_FILE_1_003900.log` created as 39th minute, and
- `MY_TEST_FILE_1_004201.log` created at 42nd minute and 1st second, etc.

I tried finding this file using command:

```
find . -name "MY_TEST_FILE_1_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].log" -print
```

and it listed all the log files for the day.

When I tried the same thing as:

```
find . -name "MY_TEST_FILE_1_[0-9]{6}.log" -print
```

I am not able to list any.

Could you please tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

A shellglob pattern is not the same as a regex.

Try 'find -regex' instead.

Comment: I am giving like this: find -regex 'MY_TEST_FILE_1_[0-9]{6}.log'

Comment: But it did not work. No matching patters were returned

Comment: Do I need to mention the regex-type?

Comment: try find . -regex '.*/MY_TEST_FILE_1_[0-9]{6}.log' instead - noticed the find DOT after find and the dot * slash in the regex

Comment: [mmm751@prodserverl uts]$ find . -regex '.*/prod/prod/fc/sysout/FC11-FILE_1_[0-9]{6}.log'
[mmm751@prodserverl uts]$  --> Returned no results :(